# JQuery Dialog position beside text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an html textbox and I want a jquery dialog to show up next to it when I click on a textbox of type "time". For example:

[image: what I want]

What I have so far:

HTML:
`Time <input id="theTime" class="time" name="inputTime" type="text">`

JQuery:

```
$(".time").click(function(e) {      
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
    modal: false,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    position: $(this).position()
    });

    $("#dialog-message").dialog("open");
});
```

The position is wrong with the above code. My dialog is not showing up in the correct position. How do I make it appear right of the textbox like in the picture?

Comment: Where does it show up? Surely, you just need to apply an offset to the position that you have given it?

Comment: The position is showing up in the centre of the window. The position coming from the textbox is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work!

    `position: {
            my: "left bottom", 
            at: "right bottom",
            of: $(this)
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Make the dialog-message absolutely positioned,

```
$("#dialog-message").css("position","absolute")
```